# How to specify to the Java VM the -d32 parameter

Tags: java, watij

I recently downloaded watij. on their website they say

> Note: If you are running on a Mac you must add `-d32` to your Java VM parameters.

I was wondering what the steps are to do this since they do not specify.

Comment: What does "accessing internet" mean in context to your question?

Comment: just since watij is used to access the internet..which is what i will ultimately try to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding -d32 to vm parameters means, when you run your app:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java HelloWorld
```

Instead you do this:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
java -d32 HelloWorld
```

It specifies that the program will run in 32bit architecture.

To set JVM arguments from **Eclipse**, do this:
1. Right click on the class you want to run.
2. Click run configurations
3. Go to arguments tab and write "-d32" under VM arguments text box.