# How to use PyCharm in 32 bit mode

Tags: python, pycharm

There is a way to run Pycharm in 32bit mode for reducing memory consumption. Where can I set that. (Pycharm has documented this, but I can't find the google phrase to get me to that page.)

Comment: I never knew about it, my pycharm on macosx is performing better now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you are looking for [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Comment: +1, I just landed on this document, finding a linux alternative for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively set VM options from your pycharm path **$PATH/pycharm/pycharm-2.7.1/bin** in file **pycharm64.vmoptions** 
example:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx800m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which OS you are running, but since pycharm is built over the JVM, you can pass this [argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603294/how-to-specify-to-the-java-vm-the-d32-parameter) to the JVM launch parameters, which will force JVM to run in 32bit mode: `-d32`